# Temperatures on surfaces of THEORETICAL adiabatic system

Tags: physics

If a theoretical system is adiabatic and can't exchange heat with it's surroundings, is the exterior surface theoretically the same temperature as the surroundings and is the interior surface theoretically the same temperature as the the system itself? and if so, how does this not break the definition of heat as energy that flows from something at a hotter temperature to something at a lower temperature?

Comment: Your observation frame is interior system and that is adiabatic, not outside world. To keep  inner wall temperature equal to inner system, you don't need any energy flow, you need to stop energy flow using shielding and controllable heat source so it doesn't exchange energy with inner system but it changes outside energy which is out of your observation window. This question should be on physics-sub-domain of stack, not here.

Comment: This question is not related to programming and belongs to the [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Think of it as heat flowing from the hot part to the cold part *very slowly.*